# Is there a way to use unleash-client-java with an Unleash Proxy?

Tags: java, unleash

We use [Unleash](https://www.getunleash.io/) with an [Unleash Proxy](https://github.com/Unleash/unleash-proxy) in our cloud and want to use the Unleash Proxy inside our Java Services.
For the feature toggle service there exists the Java sdk [unleash-client-java](https://github.com/Unleash/unleash-client-java) but I couldn't find a way to use it with the Unleash Proxy.

Is there a way to use this or another Java SDK, or should we build our own proxy-client when we want to use the Unleash Proxy in a Java backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server-side java SDK should provide the same functionalities as the proxy but inside your Java process, but if you have good reasons to use the proxy, there's an experimental flag you can use `expServerSideSdkConfig.tokens`: https://github.com/Unleash/unleash-proxy#experimental-configuration-options

If that works for you I'd suggest you try out https://github.com/Unleash/unleash-edge which is a [proxy on steroids](https://github.com/Unleash/unleash-edge/#why-choose-unleash-edge-over-the-unleash-proxy) and in particular it supports connecting a backend SDK without any experimental flag. Also, unleash-edge is the successor of unleash-proxy and should be backward compatible with it.